# implicit declaration of function 'time' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|

Tags: c, srand

Whenever I try to use `srand` function I get this **warning**

```
"implicit declaration of function 'time' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|"
```

and a **windows error report** appears when **running the compiled file**,
I'm a novice to c programming, I found this on a text book, but it doesn't work for me.

```
  srand (time());  
  int x= (rand()%10) +1;  
  int y= (rand()%10) +1;  
  printf("\nx=%d,y=%d", x,y);
```

What do I need to correct this?

Answer (score 48):

You need to make sure that you `#include` the right headers, in this case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // rand(), srand()
#include <time.h>    // time()
```

When in doubt, check the man pages:

[$ man rand](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand)

[$ man time](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time)

One further problem: `time()` requires an argument, which can be `NULL`, so your call to `srand()` should be:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: thanks for answering..  i hv included the stdlib.h ,but after including time.h it gives me another error 
error: too few arguments to function 'time'

Comment: the code i included works fine on online compilers like code pad..  im using codeblocks ide on my pc

Comment: man rand may not work as expected. There are other utilities named rand

Answer (score 1):

Note that `time()` function uses current time (expressed in seconds since 1970) both in its return value and in its address argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and the problem was that in windows you need to include `sys/time.h`, but in linux you need `time.h` and I didn't notice.

I fixed this by adding a simple platform check:

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <sys/time.h>
#else
#include <time.h>
#endif
```

*Note that this is for windows and linux, because that's what I needed for my program.*